# Add 3D view to a QWidget based UI

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to add a 3D view to an existing [QMainWindow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html) with menus, status bar and so on. I understand there are two ways to achieve this:

- option 1: Use [createWindowContainer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#createWindowContainer) to create a container that will host a Qt3DWindow inside the root QMainWindow
- option 2: Use [QGLWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qglwidget.html) ([since new QOpenGlWidget is not available yet in pyqt5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html#qtopengl-module)) and reimplement methods initializeGl, paintGl and resizeGl

### Option 1

Option 1 is not working, I have the following code below

```
class View3D(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.view = Qt3DWindow()
        self.createWindowContainer(self.view);

        # put some nodes in the scene
        scene = createScene()
        # Camera
        camera = self.view.camera()
        camera.lens().setPerspectiveProjection(45.0, 16.0 / 9.0, 0.1, 1000.0)
        camera.setPosition(QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, 40.0))
        camera.setViewCenter(QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))

        # For camera controls.
        camController = QFirstPersonCameraController(scene)
        camController.setLinearSpeed(50.0)
        camController.setLookSpeed(180.0)
        camController.setCamera(camera)

        # assign root node to the view
        view.setRootEntity(scene)
```

This View3D Widget is then added to the QMainWindow's layout. For some reason this fails with error "RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type Qt3DWindow has been deleted".

My guess is that PyQt only keeps track of a single main window, and when the Qt3DWindow is created, the QMainWindow is released and the program crashes.

Also, this method feels kind of a hack, adding a window inside a window. I have the feeling this is not the way to go.

### Option 2

Option 2 works for me, except that now I don't have access to the high level functions like `Qt3DWindow.camera()` or `Qt3DWindow.setRootEntity()`.

Instead, all the tutorials online show that you can draw triangles using QGLWidget but non of them go further and use/reimplement the high level interface and scenegraph.

As far as I understand, this is also not demonstrated in PyQt5 official examples in the sources. The `basicshapes-py.py` example is the closest thing to what I am trying to achieve, but instead it seems it adds a few buttons to a Qt3DWindow, which is not good for me since I need a QMainWindow as base class.

**Therefore, what is the recommended way to integrated a 3D view into a QWidget-based UI ?**

### Edit (with option 1)

New code after comments from @G.M.

```
class View3D(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.view = Qt3DWindow()
        self.container = self.createWindowContainer(self.view);

        vboxlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        vboxlayout.addWidget(self.container)
        self.setLayout(vboxlayout)

        # put some nodes in the scene
        scene = createScene()
        # Camera
        camera = self.view.camera()
        camera.lens().setPerspectiveProjection(45.0, 16.0 / 9.0, 0.1, 1000.0)
        camera.setPosition(QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, 40.0))
        camera.setViewCenter(QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))

        # For camera controls.
        camController = QFirstPersonCameraController(scene)
        camController.setLinearSpeed(50.0)
        camController.setLookSpeed(180.0)
        camController.setCamera(camera)

        # assign root node to the view
        self.view.setRootEntity(scene)
```

I get the following errors in the console:

```
QOpenGLContext::swapBuffers() called with non-exposed window, behavior is undefined
Qt3D.Renderer.Backend: bool __cdecl Qt3DRender::Render::GraphicsContext::makeCurrent(class QSurface *) makeCurrent failed
Qt3D.Renderer.Backend: bool __cdecl Qt3DRender::Render::GraphicsContext::makeCurrent(class QSurface *) makeCurrent failed
```

Comment: With **Option 1** you need to make use of the `QWidget` returned by [`QWidget::createWindowContainer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#createWindowContainer) -- add it to a layout or whatever.  Otherwise, when it goes out of scope and is destroyed the `Qt3DWindow` it manages will also be destroyed leading to the error messages you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've made some progress. Program now starts, however the 3D scene remains blank and the console logs the following error: `QOpenGLContext::swapBuffers() called with non-exposed window, behavior is undefined`. Any ideas ? I will edit my code to show the new version

Comment: @G.M. If you post an aswer, I'll accept it because it has solved my problem. I've opened a separate question for my subsequent issue here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262716/integrating-a-pyqt3d-window-into-a-qmainwindow