# Integrating a PyQt3D window into a QMainWindow

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

We can use [`QWidget.createWindowContainer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#createWindowContainer) to add a 3D view into a QMainWindow (a window with menus, status bar, etc).

However, I found that this approach does not work, the windows opens up but fails to render the 3D contents.

It also displays the error

```
QOpenGLContext::swapBuffers() called with non-exposed window, behavior is undefined
```

Here is a sample code that compares this approach with a native PyQt3D (that is not capable of using QWidgets to build a complete UI)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAction, QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, qApp, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QSplitter
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap, QPainter, QImage, QMatrix4x4, QQuaternion, QVector3D, QColor, QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt3DCore import QEntity, QTransform, QAspectEngine
from PyQt5.Qt3DRender import QCamera, QCameraLens, QRenderAspect
from PyQt5.Qt3DInput import QInputAspect
from PyQt5.Qt3DExtras import QForwardRenderer, QPhongMaterial, QCylinderMesh, QSphereMesh, QTorusMesh, Qt3DWindow, QOrbitCameraController

class View3D(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(View3D, self).__init__()
        self.view = Qt3DWindow()
        self.container = self.createWindowContainer(self.view)

        vboxlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        vboxlayout.addWidget(self.container)
        self.setLayout(vboxlayout)

        scene = createScene()

        # Camera.
        initialiseCamera(self.view, scene)

        self.view.setRootEntity(scene)

def initialiseCamera(view, scene):
    # Camera.
    camera = view.camera()
    camera.lens().setPerspectiveProjection(45.0, 16.0 / 9.0, 0.1, 1000.0)
    camera.setPosition(QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, 40.0))
    camera.setViewCenter(QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))

    # For camera controls.
    camController = QOrbitCameraController(scene)
    camController.setLinearSpeed(50.0)
    camController.setLookSpeed(180.0)
    camController.setCamera(camera)

def createScene():
    # Root entity.
    rootEntity = QEntity()

    # Material.
    material = QPhongMaterial(rootEntity)

    # Torus.
    torusEntity = QEntity(rootEntity)
    torusMesh = QTorusMesh()
    torusMesh.setRadius(5)
    torusMesh.setMinorRadius(1)
    torusMesh.setRings(100)
    torusMesh.setSlices(20)

    torusTransform = QTransform()
    torusTransform.setScale3D(QVector3D(1.5, 1.0, 0.5))
    torusTransform.setRotation(
            QQuaternion.fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), 45.0))

    torusEntity.addComponent(torusMesh)
    torusEntity.addComponent(torusTransform)
    torusEntity.addComponent(material)

    # Sphere.
    sphereEntity = QEntity(rootEntity)
    sphereMesh = QSphereMesh()
    sphereMesh.setRadius(3)

    sphereEntity.addComponent(sphereMesh)
    sphereEntity.addComponent(material)

    return rootEntity

class Application(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #
        view3d = View3D()
        self.setCentralWidget(view3d)
        self.show()

# Approach 1 - Integrate Qt3DWindow into a QMainWindow
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Application()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

'''
# Approach 2 - A native Qt3DWindow
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    view = Qt3DWindow()

    scene = createScene()
    initialiseCamera(view, scene)

    view.setRootEntity(scene)
    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
'''
```

Any ideas on how to correctly use `QWidget.createWindowContainer` for adding a 3D view to a classic QMainWindow ?

Comment: I don't have the PyQt5 bindings for `Qt3D` installed so I can't test directly, but... re-implementing the code in `C++` (simple line-by-line conversion basically) results in a working example (Qt5.10.0 + Linux).

Comment: So it coud be a bug with PyQt. I'll contact their support and keep you posted.

Comment: You confirm though that both approaches work for you ?

Comment: Before going any further, can you check the indentation in your code.  Are `initialiseCamera` and `createScene` really free functions or are they members of class `View3D`?

Comment: They are both free functions

Comment: Ok, so using a `C++` version of your example both approaches used in your code appear to work as expected.  Not sure which version of `Qt` you're using but if it's not the latest then it might be worth updating.

Comment: I am using the latest version of PyQt5 5.9.2 that ships with Qt. I am now facing another issue with a dead simple code -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48303984/dead-simple-pyqt5-code-fails-if-using-a-function-to-start-the-program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Approach 1, your `scene` variable in View3D goes out of scope as soon as the `__init__()` method ends. It is then garbage collected by Python, leaving nothing to be displayed.

In Approach 2, `scene` remains in scope throughout the execution of the program, so there's no problem.

I changed the three occurrences of `scene` in `__init__()` to `self.scene`, thereby keeping a reference to it. Approach 1 and Approach 2 now both work as expected.

Approach 1 still gives the error

```
QOpenGLContext::swapBuffers() called with non-exposed window, behavior is undefined
```

but it doesn't seem to cause problems.